# In wsl2, can i get standard output into clip board of windows side like pbcopy in mac os?

Tags: shell

I want to copy and paste outputs of commands in wsl2 into applications running in windows side, without touching mouse. Can i get that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Windows binaries, so `clip.exe` can be used.

```
echo Hello World | clip.exe
```